# AWS::S3::SignatureDoesNotMatch exception when copying/renaming a non-latin named file in S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, amazon-s3

I got this exception only for files with Hebrew characters:

> AWS::S3::SignatureDoesNotMatch (The
>   request signature we calculated does
>   not match the signature you provided.
>   Check your key and signing method.)

The code, after establishing the connection to S3, is:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.rename(
  resource_file_name,
  new_resource_file_name,
  bucket,
  {:content_type => resource_content_type} )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encoding only the first file name fixed the problem:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.rename(
  URI.encode(resource_file_name),
  new_resource_file_name,
  bucket,
  {:content_type => resource_content_type} )
```

Comment: I'd love if someone could explain what is the logic behind this, and whether it's a bug...